# Calculate transistor current output

Tags: power-supply, transistors, current

I want to light up an LED strip via an Arduino (ESP8266)

The Arduino’s GPIO has a maximum output of 12mA. It is not enough to power a 5m length LED strip.

An obvious solution is to use a transistor to increase the current. I’ve followed an internet tutorial that used a TIP31 transistores, but my lights were too dim. The solution provided on [this answer (RGB LED strip is too dim)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52532/rgb-led-strip-is-too-dim) is to halve the resistance to 200ohms and even that may not be enough because the current needed is about 2A per channel (6A total). They pointed to me that I could use a Darlington pair to increase even more the current and I’ve decided to try it out but before I could try someone said that it could burn my LEDs.

I can’t replace this LED strip in less than 3 weeks (shipping to my city is hell) and I would like to do it safely.

So um trying to figure out which resistor and which transistor I should use.

Some formulas I already know:

- amps needed per channel: (#LEDS / 3) * 20mA => 2A
- watts needed: V * I => 12V * (#LEDS / 3) * 20mA => 24W * 3 => 72W => 90W to be safe

This is the suggested circuit that someone said it will work and someone else said it would burn my LEDs
[image: Suggested circuit]

So I’ve decided to learn how to choose a transistor and a resistance, I’ve found this [datasheet for the TIP31](https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/datasheets/TIP31.pdf) but I can’t decode its math.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: You could always put a current limiting device somewhere in there. A plain resistor will work, or a more advanced solution with a transistor and some feedback circuitry (essentially using a linear regulator as a current limiter)

Comment: In any case, you want to look at the DC current gain rating, as well as the base-emitter forward voltage rating. Those will tell you most of what you need to know.

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m new to electronics, can you elaborate? I’m having trouble exactly with that, calculating DC current gain based on datasheet information. I’m unable to grasp what should I be using to calculate the emitter‘s output current

Comment: The emitter current is simply the sum of the base and collector currents. You can usually treat it as just being equal to the collector current, as the base current is quite small.

Comment: You typically do not design based on just the DC gain of the transistor.  This varies a lot and will be unstable.  Depending on the Vf of your LEDs, you may also be dissipating too much power in Q2 and burn it up.  If your goal is to keep the circuit simple, a power resistor in series with D1 may be a solution.

Comment: @Felthry I'm lost. The emitter current isn't based on the current provided by the base?

Comment: @evildemonic Since the ESP8266 has a maximum of 12mA I cant control the channel directly, isn't that the point of a transistor? To control how much current the adjacent circuit can supply?

Comment: It is based on the base current. The collector current is equal to β times the base current, so the emitter current is (β+1) times the base current.

Comment: It's unclear from your question how many LEDs you have or what their type is. This is important information so get describing....

Comment: @Felthry yes this is what I want, given the datasheet on the question, where is beta? How do I calculate beta?

Comment: I meant for you to add a resistor, not to remove the transistors.

Comment: Beta varies widely and is unstable, this is why we don't design with it.  It is only in the datasheet so you can see if it is "good enough".  Set the gain with resistors instead.

Comment: @Andyaka the point of the question is to calculate the current for any strip of any size and type. I can calculate the resistance of the strip, the voltage needed, the maximum current and the potency. But I need to control the channel current via an Arduino

Comment: Then the point of my comment is clearly lost on you.

Comment: @evildemonic give me a way to calculate this. I think this is what I need

Comment: @NicosKaralis What evildemonic said (and what Andy said, too). While it's important to know beta (it's labelled in this datasheet as DC current gain, and you might also see it called hfe), you don't want to rely on it. Beta varies dramatically with temperature within a single transistor, and it varies widely between different transistors, even of the same part number.

Answer (score 0):

The LED strip is most likely to have current limiting built in to it, so the configuration shown above should work. If you can plug in your LED strip to a 12V supply and measure the current with a meter and it is within spec then switching the LED strip with a low side switch should be fine without additional current limiting.

If the strip does not have current limiting then you will need to add it.

Let's talk about your switch, it needs work. Q1 will source a lot of current in the the base of Q2. It would be like plugging the base of Q2 directly into the 12V line, if you try this you will probably see smoke.

Either put a resistor to limit the current in between Q1 and Q2 (but enough to turn Q2 on fully). Do not exceed the TIP31 base current which is 1A.